# What do you call someone who chooses another way to see things?

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing about a character who is unique and prefers not to settle when it comes to a certain perspective. She chooses another way to see things. Is there any word to describe this?

Comment: She is a free thinker.

Answer (score 1):

**Iconoclast** is the first word that comes to mind. If the person you're talking about refuses to adhere to conventional beliefs and ideas, she can be called an *iconoclast*. Her views are *iconoclastic*.

She can be called a **maverick** if she is an independent thinker.

**Maverick**:

> an unorthodox or independent-minded person.

If she is oddly different from the others, in terms of her perspective, you can call her **eccentric**.(Note that this word has a positive connotation)

**Eccentric:**

> (of a person or their behaviour) unconventional and slightly strange.

Source: Oxford Dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

"***Nonconformist***" is a fairly common word for someone who doesn't go along with other people's beliefs or actions.

Answer (score 0):

**Contrarian** is the word which describes this type of behavior.

**con·trar·i·an** - 
kənˈtre(ə)rēən,kän-/

*noun*

1.
a person who opposes or rejects popular opinion

*adjective*

1.
opposing or rejecting popular opinion; going against current practice.
"the comment came more from a contrarian disposition than moral conviction"

Comment: And the quoted material is taken from where? Please edit source citations into your answer.